# how to extract python argparse optional value

Tags: python

my code is:

```
parser.add_argument("-c","config", action='store_true',help='help text here')
```

if I issue a command : `python myprog.py -c myconfig.txt`, the value gets stored in `myconfig.txt`. How do I store this value into a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take an argument, don't use `action='store_true'`. This is for setting a boolean flag, like `--verbose` for example. Instead you need to specify the type of the argument you want to take. Here we use `type=str` (which is the default):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c","--config", type=str, help='help text here')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.config:
    print "the value of config is {}".format(args.config)
```

Comment: Thans so much sir, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! I found the tutorial in the docs very helpful for brushing up: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html